# Is Xamarin.CommunityToolkit CamaraView External Camera Option UWP only?

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, uwp, xamarin.android, xamarin.communitytoolkit

I am currently working on a Xamarin. Forms-based android app that will use an external USB camera. On XCT I found this CameraView that does more than I need but only on built-in cams on a device.

After some poking around in the XCT repository only reference I found about an external option of the cam view was on UWP implementation.

The main question is: does this even works on mobile? If so, are there any known good examples?

**EDIT**:

Summery of what I want to achieve: connecting an external USB camera to Android ant use External Camera Option on Camera View. I want to know is there a "standard" way to wire up implemented source to the CameraView.

Answer (score 0):

> The main question is: does this even works on mobile? If so, are there any known good examples?

Yes, it works on mobile.

You could download the code sample from GitHub for reference.
https://github.com/xamarin/XamarinCommunityToolkit/blob/main/samples/XCT.Sample/Pages/Views/CameraViewPage.xaml

Comment: Thank you for the answer. The thing is that I tried this example already. The only indication that it works with external cams is this comment:
``` // You can also set it to Default and External ```
Sample works on mobile, that is clear. but it has no further indications that it would work with external cams. 
For external USB cam to work with Android you first have to implement some stuff. If it does work, how it wires up with CameraView? is there a custom renderer for it?

Comment: I have checked all the official documents and official samples. No more details of samples for the external camera device. I do not have the external device to test. You could post this in issue of the package for further help. https://github.com/xamarin/XamarinCommunityToolkit/issues